# How to iterate over a CSV file and create an object from the first element and the rest using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code:

```
   def _load_data_set(self, dataset_file):
        data_frame = pandas.read_csv(dataset_file)
        table = data_frame.values.tolist()

        rows = len(table)
        patients = []
        for i in range(rows):
            first = table[i][0]
            rest = table[i]
            rest.pop(0)
            p = PatientDataSet(first, rest)
            patients.append(p)
        return patients
```

This code is basically, iterates over a CSV file (with a header) and for each row it splits the first place and the rest and creates a list of `PatientDataSet` object.

The input: CSV file with header.
The output: List of `PatientDataSet` objects.

Although it works, I really don't like how I implemented it because I pop the first column and the code looks really ugly. Is it possible to suggest how would be better to do it?

Comment: No one can really answer this question without a representative example of the csv file, and the expected result, given the sample data, as [formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), no data screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this:

```
def _load_data_set(self, dataset_file):
    df = pandas.read_csv(dataset_file, index_col=0)
    return [PatientDataSet(first, rest.tolist()) for first, rest in df.iterrows()]
```

Passing `index_col=0` to `read_csv()` naturally separates the first column from the rest.

`iterrows()` gives you the index and the values for each row, which is exactly what you need.

You may be able to remove `.tolist()` if your `PatientDataSet` does not actually need a `list` but can accept `rest` directly as a Pandas Series.  That would be better, to avoid an unnecessary conversion.